# Why can't scoped_ptr be used with STL containers?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, stl, containers

The boost documentation page [reads](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.htm)

> **`scoped_ptr`** cannot be used in C++ Standard Library containers. Use **`shared_ptr`** if you need a smart pointer that can.

I'm supposing that being **non-copyable** would be an obstacle for `scoped_ptr` but since c++11, as far as some containers are concerned, we can :

- Constuct in place with `emplace_back` etc
- Move resources without copying

So what's the reason for scoped_ptr being non useable with STL containers ?

Comment: Why not use `std::unique_ptr` instead ?

Comment: If C++11 is an option, use `std::unique_ptr`, which is in every regard superior to `scoped_ptr`. The latter only existed as a cheap, feasible half-way measure that did as much as it could sanely without move semantics (by contrast with the broken `std::auto_ptr`).

Comment: @Jarod42 I'm wondering whether usage is prohibited (so what's the reason ?) or it's just a case of an out of date documentation.

Comment: @KerrekSB I would be lying if I said that C++11 is not an option; then how would move semantics be available. It's a question on `scoped_ptr` specificaly (Unless it's a valid thing to replace `scoped_ptr` with `unique_ptr` from a code base and never hear of it again)

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou: Anywhere you have a locally scoped `scoped_ptr<T>`, you can replace it with a `unique_ptr<T> const`. Anywhere you have a `scoped_ptr<T>` in a standard container, you can replace it with a `unique_ptr<T>` and your life will be happier and improved overall.

Comment: @Mankarse: At least you could say that code that would *break* if you replaced `boost::scoped_ptr` with `std::unique_ptr` would be pathological. You could do some SFINAE conditional on mobility and switch code paths based on that, but... why? :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation is somewhat out-of-date. `Boost.ScopedPtr` is an old library, and the maintainers have not cared to keep the documentation in-sync with the latest developments in C++.

In theory a `scoped_ptr`-like class could work (as evidenced by `std::unique_ptr`); but in reality, `boost::scoped_ptr` cannot be usefully used in many standard containers, since it has a private copy constructor and no move constructor. In particular, `std::vector` and `std::deque` require that their contents be move-constructible.

`scoped_ptr` *can* be used in node-based containers (since such containers do not require that their contents be move-constructible), if only a limited subset of the container's interface is used. Code such as the following is valid:

```
std::list<boost::scoped_ptr<int>> list;
list.emplace_back(new int(16));

std::map<int, boost::scoped_ptr<int>> map;
map.emplace(
    std::piecewise_construct,
    std::forward_as_tuple(10),
    std::forward_as_tuple(new int(14)));
```

Even so, it is needlessly painful compared to just using `std::unique_ptr` (since using `std::unique_ptr` will allow you to use a far larger proportion of the standard container's interfaces).

Comment: I would say the doc is a little out-of-date, as it suggests to use `auto_ptr` for the transfer of ownership...

Comment: @Jarod42: Well... of course the documentation is somewhat out-of-date (it doesn't even suggest that `scoped_ptr` is deprecated in favour of `const std::unique_ptr`). But it is still valid with regards to standard containers (at least, for `vector` and `deque`).

Answer (score 3):

As state is the doc,

> It supplies a basic "resource acquisition is initialization" facility, **without shared-ownership or transfer-of-ownership** semantics. Both its **name** and enforcement of semantics (by being noncopyable) signal its intent to retain ownership solely within the current scope.

and

> Q. Why doesn't scoped_ptr have a release() member?
>   A. When reading source code, it is valuable to be able to draw conclusions about program behavior based on the types being used. If scoped_ptr had a release() member, it would become possible to transfer ownership of the held pointer, weakening its role as a way of limiting resource lifetime to a given context.

`scope_ptr` exists to be safer that the deprecated `auto_ptr` and to represent RAII.
Now in C++11, we have `std::unique_ptr` to represent unique ownership.